Why can't you initialize a single row of a 2d array in c++?
Consider a 2D array (with a compile or runtime constant for the first dimension, and a compile time constant for the second). e.g. int arr[10][3]; or int arr[n][3];
Why isn't it possible to do something like this: arr[0] = {1,2,3,4}; or arr[n-1] = {1,2,3,4};
Is that a c++ standard choice or is this functionality simply not needed / there a way that I missed to do something like this?

Your syntax is about assignment  rather than initializiation - you can initialize multidimensional arrays just fine, but assigning to an array is a different story

int arr[10][4] = {{1,2,3,4}}; would work just fine to initialize the first row (and zero the rest of them implicitly). But as UnholySheep notes, assigning arr[0] later is no longer initialization.

Works just fine for vector<>s instead of C-style arrays (but not because it's explicitly handled, as a part of bigger features). For arrays, just not in the standard. It was not in C initially, was not added in C++, and nobody got to publishing a corresponding proposal and pushing it through compiler vendors and the committee since.

You gotta set the wayback machine for the 1970s to really understand arrays. Back when all you had at your fingertips was half a K of RAM and the processing power of a potato chip your options were really limited and the languages of the time reflected that.

std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 10> will let you treat arrays just like regular objects.

It isn’t possible for several reasons. Primarily because the syntax does not permit it. But likely because that would be such an unusual need.
You can get close enough:
int arr[10][5] =
{
    {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {0}
};

You don’t technically need to specify any thing that is not zeroed:
int arr[10][5] =
{
    {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {1,2,3,4,5}
};


You don't technically need to specify anything that is not not zeroed, I believe; or, cutting the negations, you don't need to specify anything that is zeroed; or, inverting the remaining negation: you must specify only what is not zeroed ;-).
